Appropriate Font for Figure Legends in Elsevier's Journal
I'm preparing a manuscript for submission to Elsevier's journal Chaos, Solitons & Fractals. In the past, I've had issues with the fonts used in axis labels and figure legends being rejected for conference submissions. To avoid similar problems with this journal submission, I want to ensure that the fonts I use in my figures are acceptable.
Question:
What font should I use for the legend and axis labels in my figures to comply with Elsevier's guidelines for Chaos, Solitons & Fractals? or in general?
Context:

I'm using LaTeX for manuscript preparation.
I want to ensure consistency and compliance with Elsevier's formatting standards.
Previous issues were due to fonts not matching required specifications.

Additional Information:

Any tips on setting the fonts in Matplotlib (if applicable) would be greatly appreciated.
If there are any specific packages or commands in LaTeX that help in achieving the correct font, please do share.

Thank you for your help!

Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you asked the support of the journal?

This is not really a TeX question as much as it is an article submission question.
My suspicion is that your article was flagged because the text was either too small to read or because the font was not embedded and they didn't have it. You can solve the embedding problem by using fonts that every printer that supports PostScript is guaranteed to have (e.g., Times, Helvetica, Palatino) or by using a PDF with the fonts embedded.
Some journals have a more helpful guide to authors that gives tips on this sort of thing. This particular journal's guide is not particularly helpful in this area, and it appears this is Elsevier-wide. I took a peek at one article, though, and it looks like using Times or Helvetica should be fine.
That said, I would make your figures the way you want them (including whatever typeface you want to use), embed the fonts in a PDF, and go with it.

Thanks for you answer. I was not aware of that!
